# Chroma db persist to local - bad allocation error

Tags: python, allocation, persist, vector-database, chromadb

I'm currently working on loading pre-vectorized text data into a Chroma vector database with jupyter notebook. However, I've encountered an issue where I'm receiving a "bad allocation" error.

To provide some context, I have an existing collection in my local disk that contains 500K rows of text data. When I attempt to reload this existing collection and add more text data to it, I encounter the "bad allocation" error.

Based on my understanding, I believe that the error occurs because the client is unable to handle such a large file and send it to the RAM. My question is, how should the design be structure our code trying to import and  persist the data so that we can avoid memory allocation error ?

I've tried doing a persist(client_wiki_ja.persist()) after a batch and after a single file that contains 100k text data rows, but it remains to have the same issue.

**Client initialize and retrieving existing collection from local disk**

```
client_wiki_ja = chromadb.Client(Settings(
    chroma_db_impl="duckdb+parquet",
    persist_directory= database_directory 
))

cohere_ef  = embedding_functions.CohereEmbeddingFunction(
    api_key=api_key_embedding_cohere, 
    model_name="multilingual-22-12")

  
collection_wiki_ja = client_wiki_ja.get_collection(name=collection_name,embedding_function=cohere_ef) # Get a collection object from an existing collection, by name. Will raise an exception if it's not found.
```

**Import text data to vector database**

```
def load_files(batch_size=500,max_files_load=2,startFile_index=4): # startFile_index starts from 0 (e.g.train-00003-of-00035-99c97d6c1602f565.parquet, then startFile_index=3 )
    
    directory = r"C:\Users\liewg\Desktop\p005-butumon-go\wikipedia-22-12-ja-embeddings\data" # wiki data located
    file_list = os.listdir(directory)
    counter = 0  # how many files to insert  

    for idx, filename in enumerate(file_list): # mutliple file
        if idx < startFile_index:
            continue  # Skip the first two files
        
        file_path = os.path.join(directory, filename)  # single parquet file   
        print(file_path)
        df = pd.read_parquet(file_path, engine='pyarrow')
        # df = df.head(3)
         

        df['emb'] = df['emb'].apply(lambda x: x.tolist())
        print("finished convert to list...")
        # print("number of files: ",df.count())

        rows = df# .head(10000)


        for i in tqdm(range(0, len(rows), batch_size)): # per file 
            i_end = min(len(rows), i+batch_size) # gets end point of a batch
            batch = rows[i:i_end]   

            embeds_batch = [ emb for emb in batch['emb']]
            text_batch = [ text for text in batch['text']]
            metadatas_batch = [ {"source": title} for title in batch['title']]
            ids_batch = [ str(id) for id in batch['id']]

            
            collection_wiki_ja.add(
                            embeddings= embeds_batch,
                            documents= text_batch,
                            metadatas=metadatas_batch,
                            ids = ids_batch
                    )
            print("batch:", i)
            print("persist starts")
            client_wiki_ja.persist()  # for after initial
            print("persist ends")

            # if i == 2: 
            #     break 
        print("completed")

        

        counter += 1
        if counter == max_files_load : 
            break
```

**Error**

````
Error                                     Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[9], line 1
----> 1 load_files()

Cell In[8], line 42, in load_files(batch_size, max_files_load, startFile_index)
     40 print("batch:", i)
     41 print("persist starts")
---> 42 client_wiki_ja.persist()  # for after initial
     43 print("persist ends")
     45 # if i == 2: 
     46 #     break 

File ~\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\chromadb\api\local.py:544, in LocalAPI.persist(self)
    536 @override
    537 def persist(self) -> bool:
    538     """Persist the database to disk.
    539 
    540     Returns:
    541         True if the database was persisted successfully
    542 
    543     """
--> 544     self._db.persist()
    545     return True

File ~\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\chromadb\db\duckdb.py:473, in PersistentDuckDB.persist(self)
    470 if self._conn.query("SELECT COUNT() FROM embeddings") == 0:
    471     return
--> 473 self._conn.execute(
    474     f"""```
    475     COPY
    476         (SELECT * FROM embeddings)
    477     TO '{self._save_folder}/chroma-embeddings.parquet'
    478         (FORMAT PARQUET);
    479 """
    480 )
    482 self._conn.execute(
    483     f"""
    484     COPY
   (...)
    488 """
    489 )

Error: Invalid Error: bad allocation
````